# Regex to remove white space from this exact pattern

Tags: c#, regex, whitespace

I am trying to remove the white space that is in this header that appears after the ":" character

```
batman: 100
robin: OFXSGML
superman: 102
wonderwoman: NONE
joker: USASCII
harley: 1252
aquaman: NONE
flash: NONE
iris: NONE
```

this is a regex pattern to match this exact header but I keep running into problems trying to delete the white space any help that can be offered is appreciated

```
^batman:\s100 robin:\sOFXSGML superman:\s102 wonderwoman:\s+NONE joker:\sUSASCII harley: 1252 aquaman:\s+NONE flash:\sNONE iris:\sNONE$
```

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(text, @":\s+", ":");`

Answer (score 3):

In your pattern you are using spaces, but if you want to match all lines you can replace them with `\s` every time you cross a newline.

Then you can after process it replacing `:\s` with `:` but note that the pattern [is very precise match](https://regex101.com/r/WA0oy8/1).

---

If you want to be more flexible, You can use a capture group to capture all before the `:` and then match the spaces after it.

```
^([^\s:]+:)[\p{Zs}\t]+(?=\S)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([^\s:]+:)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `:` and then match the `:`
- `[\p{Zs}\t]+` Match 1+ spaces
- `(?=\S)` Postive lookahead, assert a non whitespace char to the right (if there has to be one, else you can omit this part)

In the replacement use group 1 like `$1`

[.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0FLUpT/1)

Comment: ++ve for nice solution. Could you please explain more on `[\p{Zs}\t]+` part please, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks man, this `\p{Zs}` matches [any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) Then you can combine that with a character class to also match a tab.

Answer (score 0):

This regex `(?<=:)\s` will match a single whitespaces after every `:`

```cs
var text = @"batman: 100 robin: OFXSGML superman: 102 wonderwoman: NONE joker: USASCII harley: 1252 aquaman: NONE flash: NONE iris: NONE";
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=:)\s", "");
```

Comment: please add some explenation

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be any more complex than:

```
string source = @"
batman: 100
robin: OFXSGML
superman: 102
wonderwoman: NONE
joker: USASCII
harley: 1252
aquaman: NONE
flash: NONE
iris: NONE
".Trim();

Regex  rx     = new Regex(@"(?<=:)\s+");
string result = rx.Replace(source, "");
```

- `(?<=:)` is a *zero-width positive lookbehind*: it anchors the match on a `:`, without it being a part of the match.
- `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespace characters (SP, HT, CR, LF, VT).

That changes:

```
batman: 100
robin: OFXSGML
superman: 102
wonderwoman: NONE
joker: USASCII
harley: 1252
aquaman: NONE
flash: NONE
iris: NONE
```

into

```
batman:100
robin:OFXSGML
superman:102
wonderwoman:NONE
joker:USASCII
harley:1252
aquaman:NONE
flash:NONE
iris:NONE
```

Alternatively, you can include the `:` in the match. It just changes the replacement text:

```
Regex  rx     = new Regex(@":\s+");
string result = rx.Replace(source, ":");
```

If you care about the value of the *key* preceding the colon-plus-whitespace, use *named capture groups* and a *match evaluator*.

Here the regular expression `(?<key>\w+)\s*:\s*` matches:

- `(?<key>\w+)` — a sequence of 1 or more whitespace characters (letters, digits or `_`), followed by
- `\s*` — zero or more whitespace characters, followed by
- `:` — a literal colon character, followed by
- `\s*` — zero or more whitespace characters

The match evaluator looks at the capturing group named *key*. If it is any of `batman`, `robin`, or `superman`, any whitespace preceding or following the colon is removed; otherwise, the match itself is returned unchanged.

```
Regex  rx     = new Regex(@"(?<key>\w+)\s*:\s*");
string result = rx.Replace(source, (Match m) => {
  string replacement;
  string key = m.Groups["key"].Value;
  
  switch (key) {
  case "batman":
  case "robin":
  case "superman":
    replacement = key+":";
    break;
  default:
    replacement = m.Value;
    break;
  }
  
  return replacement;
});
```